# Accept both lambda-functions and function-pointers as argument

Tags: c++, function, lambda, function-pointers

I have a function, let's say

```
void processSomething(Arg1 arg1, Function t){
    ...
    t(someVariable);
}
```

I want both of the following usages to work:

```
processSomething(myArg1, [&](SomeVariable someVar){...});
void(*myFunc)(void) = &someFunc;
processSomething(myArg1, myFunc);
```

However, I found that I can't use the lambda-way when using `void(*myFunc)(void)` as parameter declaration.
Any way to have both usages work without two separate functions or an overly complicated use of wrappers?

Comment: If you look at e.g. [the standard algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) you will see that all the functions taking a "predicate" will have it as a templated type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you have two choices:

1. Templates:

   ```
   template<class F>
   void processSomething(Arg1 arg1, F t){
   ```

   This is the preferred way as it creates more efficient code, but at the cost of possible code-duplication.
2. Using a `std::function` or such:

   ```
   void processSomething(Arg1 arg1, std::function<void(SomeVariable)> t){
   ```

   There's a runtime-cost to the indirections involved, but it will use the same code in each case.